# Equality form of second order Taylor series

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I am reading a book on optimization wherein a statement using Taylor's expansion is made without proof.

\begin{equation}
f(\mathbf{y}) = f(\mathbf{x}) + (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x})^T\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) + \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x})^T\nabla^2f(\mathbf{z})(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x})
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{x} + t(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}) $ for some $t\in[0,1]$.

How is this form obtained?

In addition, for the same $\mathbf{z}$, can I write 
\begin{equation}
f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{y}) + (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})^T\nabla f(\mathbf{y}) + \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})^T\nabla^2f(\mathbf{z})(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})
\end{equation}
i.e. switch $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that is twice differentiable we have
$$
f(y) = f(x) + (y-x) f'(x) + R_2(y-x),
$$
where $R_2(y-x)$ is the remainder (the 2 stands for the order). There is a theorem which states that
$$
R_2(y-x) = \frac{f''(z)(y-x)^2}{2!}
$$ for some $z$ between $x$ and $y$. You can prove with induction to $n$ that if your function is smooth enough (i.e. enough times differentiable) then 
$$
R_n(y-x) = \frac{f^{(n)}(z)(y-x)^n}{n!}
$$
You can find the complete proof for example in the book "Elementary analysis: the theory of calculus (Ross)". In that book it is theorem 31.5.

Now your statement is just a multivariate form of this theorem.

Comment: That was very helpful. This reference was exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!